# Lint: “<key> is not translated in <language>” error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

My Android app recently started throwing Lint errors when compiling. I'm getting `<key> is not translated in <language>.` It tells me `If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared in one language should also be translated in all other languages.`

Unlike some of the other similar questions on this subject, I'm currently only supporting one locale. Eclipse somehow has started thinking that I want to support multiple, and now throws errors when compiling. Yes, I can turn off lint checking when I'm building, or I could set this to a warning instead of a fatal error, but that's just hiding the problem, which is that Eclipse thinks there are multiple locales. How do I fix this?

**Edit:** I tracked down the source - I added a library project that had a values-da folder. Any way to get the rest of my app to ignore that folder, or do I have to just remove it?

Comment: Don't remove it. Rename it to NOT-values-da. That'll cause it to be ignored.

Comment: Is there any way to do it at a project level? The folder is in a git submodule that I'd rather not have to fork to change. Either way, if you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: So glad to see git used properly. I'd rather that not be an accepted answer, because it's a cludge. Have you looked at eclipse's resource filters? Check Project/Properties/Resource/Resource Filters and exclude the values-da recursively. It doesn't seem to affect the builder, but you might be able to hide it from lint.

Comment: I ended up having to delete it. I tried renaming it to various things (NOT-values-da, not-values-da, ignore-values-da), but it would sometimes complain about an invalid resource directory name. I don't really care about Danish support for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seemed to work for this (thanks @323go for the suggestions) was to delete the folder. Renaming the file may work for you, but I got intermittent "Invalid resource directory name" errors.